# Internet Explorer canvas.toDataURL SecurityError

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas, todataurl

I run the following code on Internet Explorer, it throws a SecurityError on the line `var canvasDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();`

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){
  canvasContext.drawImage(img,0,0);
  var canvasDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL(); // error occurs here
  console.log(canvasDataUrl);
};
img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x300';
```

What is the cause of that error, and how can I fix this ?

Comment: That usually means the image is not [clean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL). Which should not affect different browsers tho.

Comment: Are you really trying to load the image at this exact URL? As said by previous comment, this should not work in any browser, and if it does, that's a serious security bug. If you are trying to draw an other image, what kind of image is it? Maybe an SVG image?

Comment: I'm in favor of the comments above. I tested your code and it can't work in neither IE nor Chrome. *`SecurityError` means the canvas's bitmap is not origin clean; at least some of its contents have or may have been loaded from a site other than the one from which the document itself was loaded.* I guess the image src in your code snippet is virtual. If possible, you can provide the real image src so that we can have a test. Besides, the answer below can work well in IE, you can also try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try `crossOrigin`

```
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
```

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous"; 
image.onload = function (event) {
    try {
        canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 200, 200);
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL());        
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
image.src = "https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW500/1691290368/h07F7F378/"
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @pc_coder is correct, and I want to provide some information about this error, you can see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

> Because the pixels in a canvas's bitmap can come from a variety of
> sources, including images or videos retrieved from other hosts, it's
> inevitable that security problems may arise.
>
> As soon as you draw into a canvas any data that was loaded from
> another origin without CORS approval, the canvas becomes tainted. A
> tainted canvas is one which is no longer considered secure, and any
> attempts to retrieve image data back from the canvas will cause an
> exception to be thrown.
>
> If the source of the foreign content is an HTML  or SVG 
> element, attempting to retrieve the contents of the canvas isn't
> allowed.
>
> If the foreign content comes from an image obtained from either as
> HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitMap, and the image source doesn't meet
> the same origin rules, attempts to read the canvas's contents are
> blocked.
>
> Calling any of the following on a tainted canvas will result in an error:
>
> - Calling getImageData() on the canvas's context
> - Calling toBlob() on the  element itself
> - Calling toDataURL() on the canvas
>
> Attempting any of these when the canvas is tainted will cause a SecurityError to be thrown. This protects users from having private data exposed by using images to pull information from remote web sites without permission.